# Targeting multiple grains in Salt minions using API

Tags: api, salt-stack

In our infrastructure, we set multiples grains on the minion including an "environment" and "app" grain.
When we use the cli, we can get the correct minions using:

```
salt -C "G@app:middle_tier_1 and G@environment:dev" test.ping
```

But if we try to use the cherrypy api, only got a result if set only one target like:

```
[{"client":"local","tgt_type":"grain","fun":"test.ping","tgt":"G@app:middle_tier_1"}]
```

or

```
[{"client":"local","tgt_type":"grain","fun":"test.ping","tgt":"G@environment:dev"}]
```

with multiples one, don't get any

```
[{"client":"local","tgt_type":"grain","fun":"test.ping","tgt":"G@app:middle_tier_1 and G@environment:dev"}]
```

```
[{"client":"local","tgt_type":"grain","fun":"test.ping","tgt":["G@app:middle_tier_1","G@environment:dev"]}]
```

According with the documentation, i can use a list in the tgt paramenter.

I have looked their documentation fairly extensively and have found no examples of this type of minion targeting.
Is this even possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Extra info:
salt-master 2018.3.2 (Oxygen)
salt-api 2018.3.2 (Oxygen)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple grains, the tgt_type is `compound` not `grains`.

See: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/#salt-s-client-interfaces, https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html